# Add servers/platforms from backend in Aegir using drush

Tags: drupal, drush, aegir

I'm looking for automating the process of creating new server, installing packages, adding server and platform to Aegir host. I know how to do it with GUI for adding server and platform but not sure to do it from backend(CLI) using drush. Would be great if someone can provide me some reference if they are into this process.

Thanks,
Swaroop.

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent resources in the [Aegir user handbook](http://community.aegirproject.org/using). But for setting up servers and platforms, "[Manage your Aegir system from the command-line](http://community.aegirproject.org/content/manage-your-aegir-system-command-line)" might be what you are looking for. I also use "[Provision - the Aegir backend.](http://community.aegirproject.org/node/41)" for my reference when I am trying to do stuff like that.

Good luck!